# Finding all possible Jordan forms of an $ 8\times 8$ matrix given the minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

> Find all possible Jordan forms of an $ 8\times 8$ matrix given that $$t^2(t-1)^3$$ is the minimal polynomial.

I don't really know where to start so all help would be appreciated

Comment: How about listing all the possible Jordan blocks the matrix might have?

Comment: The question before this gave me a characteristic polynomial too. Working by the same logic I did for those then this would have at least one 2 block of order 1 and at least one 1 block of order 3, would this be on the right lines?

Comment: The matrix has Jordan blocks for the eigenvalues $0$ and $1$, those for the eigenvalue $0$ are of size at most $2$ by $2$ and those for the eigenvalue $1$ are of size at most $3$ by $3$, with at least one $2$ by $2$ block for the eigenvalue zero and at least one $3$ by $3$ block for the eigenvalue $1$. (So, for instance, it could have one $2$ by $2$ block with eigenvalue $0$ and two $3$ by $3$ blocks with eigenvalue $1$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $J(\alpha,k)$ be the upper Jordan block with minimal polynomial $(t-\alpha)^k$. 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 1 & 0 & \ldots & \ldots\\ 
0 & \alpha & 1 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & \alpha & \ddots & \ddots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So, there is - up to conjugation -  one possible upper Jordan form of your matrix, in dimension 5 (see the end)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
J(0,2) & 0\\
0 & J(1,3)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now, you have to extend it to dimension 8. Calling $p_1,p_2,\cdots p_k$ (resp. $q_1,q_2,\cdots q_l$) the orders of the Jordan blocks for the eigenvalue $0$ (resp.  the orders of the Jordan blocks for the eigenvalue $1$), one has 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k p_i+\sum_{i=1}^l q_i=8
$$ 
$p_i\leq 2,\ q_i\leq 3$ and at least one of the $p_i=2$ at least one of the $q_i=3$.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I think I get it thank you

Comment: OK, could you upvote then (if I really helped) ?

Comment: Yes of course, I always forget to do that

Comment: In fact all Jordan forms of order 5 are in the same conjugacy class but all different as matrices. Now, you have to extend it to dimension $8$ ...

Comment: @Stephen If you want to finish, you can have a look at the three last lines of the MO [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354164/jordan-canonical-form-and-minimal-polynomial?rq=1) and the combinatorial equations I put in the answer. Do not hesitate to interact !